# Silverlight Canvas doesn't support KeyDown?

Tags: silverlight, events, silverlight-3.0

I have this:

```
<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" KeyDown="LayoutRoot_KeyDown">
</Canvas>
```

In a newly-minted Ag 3 application in VS2008. I simply changed the default `<Grid />` to `<Canvas />` and added a `KeyDown` handler that pops a MessageBox.

But no matter how I tried, the `KeyDown` event just would never, ever fires.

Is it simply that `<Canvas />` doesn't support `KeyDown` or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have at least something inside the Canvas that can receive focus, and you will find that the event will bubble up.

You may also want to set `IsHitTestVisible="True"` on the Canvas.

Answer (score 3):

Since your `Canvas` is the "LayoutRoot" you could use the containing `UserControl` instead.

Place the property `IsTabStop="true"` on the `UserControl`.  In the `Loaded` event call `this.Focus()`.  Attach your KeyDown handler to the `UserControl` instead of the `Canvas`.

As long as the plugin itself has the focus (which you can ensure with a little Javascript) you should now get key events.