# silverlight keydown event doesn't work

Tags: silverlight

I use VS2010, C# to develop Silverlight 4 app, I use following code in my XAML file:

```
    <Canvas x:Name="Scene" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Background="White" KeyDown="Scene_KeyDown" MouseMove="Scene_MouseMove">
```

and this is my XAML.cs file, I want to display a message box if any key is pressed (it is for test only):

```
        private void Scene_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
            MessageBox.Show("1");
    }
```

but nothing is displayed after keys are pressed! what is going wrong? should I set any property? command? tabstop? keypreview?

please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596149/silverlight-canvas-doesnt-support-keydown) will solve your problem:

> You need to have at least something inside the Canvas that can receive
>   focus, and you will find that the event will bubble up.

Comment: I tested all of mentioned notes but I could get nothing! is there any sample showing it?